# How to create empty document in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, desktop-environments

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10, but in right click only "New Folder" no "empty document"!
How to create new empty document now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in a terminal:

```bash
touch "$HOME/Templates/Empty document"
```

"Empty document" should now show in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

One way to create a blank file is through the command line. Look for the Terminal and type

```
touch fileName
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Remember where you executed the command. It's  mostly in your home directory `/home/username` so the file should be located there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty file called `blank file` in the templates folder.